# Base64 encoding and viewing an image

Tags: php, android, bitmap, base64

What I am currently trying to do is the following:

Take a Picture, compress it to PNG, covert using Base64 and send it to a database through PHP. That all works like a charm. I can also decode the Base64 string and display the photo perfectly.

However, the problems seems to be that when I view the picture on my browser, it is not the same size as it should be (or at least I think).

This is the image that I took encoded and displayed in browser: 
[image]

Regardless of the phone, (Also tested on a Galaxy SII), the issue still remains. Do you guys have any idea what may be happening? Here are some ideas that I have but not sure... 
1. Compressing the image too much - or when it compresses it changes something 2.Base64 encoding/decoding is messing up the photo and not displaying it correctly 3. When i place the image in an image view it modifies the size.

Again, It seems like that full image is not getting sent through, cause there is no way an image even a Galaxy sII image looks that small.

Here is the code that I am using:
Android:

```
// CONVERT:
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
        Log.d(TAG, "AFTER. Height: " + picture.getHeight() + " Width: " + picture.getWidth());
        final byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

        //encode to string
        String photoTest = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);

//Camera on activity for result - save it as a bmp and place in imageview
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            // do something
        }

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "result ok");

            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            picture = (Bitmap) b.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(picture);
        }
    }
```

IMAGE VIEW IN ANDROID:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
```

PHP:

```
$image = base64_decode($_POST['image_data']);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is nothing to do with Base64 and all about how you are converting the image. If the image is too small when you decode it, it was too small when it was encoded. Base64 stores binary data in an ASCII format - the data is exactly the same when decoded, if it comes out wrong, it was wrong when you started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply DaveRandom. If I am understanding what you wrote correctly, then the issue is that the image size is not the original when passed through to the encoding. So I guess my next question would be whether theres a way to get the true size of the image.

Comment: I think that @Campadrenaline's answer is heading in the right direction - I suspect it is `picture.compress()` that is converting the image. Bare in mind this is not about "quality", as this tends to be used in terms of how compressed the image is. The problem you have is that the image is being resized, or "resampled" at some point in your client side code. You should take the compression code out, try and get it to work without it, then start playing with compression.

Comment: Got It. Well you both were right. I found out that I am only using `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` and I have to include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` otherwise android automatically scales my image down. I will post my full answer once i figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved it: Turns out that when you save the photo like I did above, it only returns the thumbnail version of the photo and not the full sized photo. I had to add EXTRA_OUTPUT to my intent, save it to the sd-card, then compress. If someone has similar issues, please message me.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but I don't understand what you mean by your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 leaves binary data exactly intact, it doesn't do resizing gimmicks. I'm guessing the problem line is `picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);`, but this isn't really my field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Correct me if I am wrong but I thought that PNG ignores the quality aspect of the compress, hence values from 100-0 dont matter. Im not sure tho

Comment: PNG doesn't ignore quality AFAIK. My understanding was that it ran multiple passes of a lossless algorithm based on the quality variable (so it's not actually a tradeoff of quality, but of encode/decode time, for size). Now I'm not so sure. Regardless, it's definitely in your image preprocessing pipeline that you're having issues. Once it's in Base64 it's basically safe from that kind of mutilation until decoded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is how i solved my problem, this method will open the default camera app, save the image to a temporary folder and convert it do Base64/ByteArray.

1 - Click Listener to open the camera app

```
// My ImageButton click Listener
ibt_foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder/";
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder/photo1.jpg";
        prepareDirectory();
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
});
```

2 - Creating folder

```
private boolean prepareDirectory() {
    try {
        if (makedirs()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean makedirs() {

    File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
    if (!tempdir.exists()) {
        tempdir.mkdirs();
    }

    /*
    // Use this if you want to delete older files
    if (tempdir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (!file.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
            }
        }
    }
    */

    return (tempdir.isDirectory());
}
```

3 - Handling result from camera app

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    System.gc(); 

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {

                // Get image
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 3;
                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

                // Converting to ByteArray and Base64
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                boolean validaCompressao = imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, outputStream);
                byte[] fotoBinario = outputStream.toByteArray();

                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(fotoBinario, Base64.DEFAULT);

                // setting image to my ImageButton
                ibt_foto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Picture Not taken",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken 2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
}
```